# Вызов функции цепочкой  после конструктора

Tags: php

Во время вызова construct объекта по сути еще несуществует, мне необходимо выцепить имя объекта путем сравнения массивов $GLOBALS во время вызова construct и после него. Чтобы автоматизировать сей процесс и выполнить одноэтапно надо сделать так, чтобы функция вызвалась в цепочке сразу после вызова конструктора. Возможно ли это реализовать в php?

Comment: Объект, как выделенная память, уже существует, конструкторы просто наполняют ячейки памяти - данными

Comment: В памяти он возможно существует, но в массиве $GLOBALS во время вызова конструктора объекта, самого объекта пока еще нет, что позволяет выцепить его имя.

Comment: Можно сохранить `$_GLOBALS` в объекте, а потом извне вызвать функцию, определяющую имя экземпляра.

Comment: А зачем такие извращения?

Comment: а если объект создается в функции? =)

Comment: Ну чтобы можно было присоединить один объект к другому специальным методом. @Sh4dow в смысле?

Comment: чувствую, изобретается мегавелосипед. Рассказывайте детальнее, что хочется сделать.

Comment: Вопрос как вызвать сразу после конструктора автоматически другую функцию, т.е чтобы объект был уже создан и можно было отследить разницу $GLOBALS в две инструкции это сделать можно, а в одну? Согласен, что велосипедом очень сильно попахивает, хочу попробовать свой вариант для работы с базой данных, когда запись в таблице является классом а ячейки(ключ->значение), представлены не элементами массива, а свойствами объекта. При этом хочу, чтобы было все динамически и не зависело от конкретной таблицы.

Comment: @culebre, 

    function &getObj () {
      print_r($GLOBALS);
      $obj = new MyClass;
      print_r($GLOBALS);
      return $obj;
      }

Comment: @Sh4dow, что-то не совсем понял, если ты про локальную область видимости, то меня это не сильно беспокоит. Ну я так и понял на это он и $GLOBALS.

Comment: Я не о том. Объект, созданный в локальном пространстве функции, в $GLOBALS вообще не появится. Соответственно таким образом и имя вытащить не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, могу предложить процедурный подход.

```
class MyClass {
  public $a = 1;
  public function __construct($objectName) {
    $GLOBALS[$objectName] = &$this;
    }
  }

new MyClass('myVar');
var_dump($myVar);
```

Но учтите, что объекты будут доступны только в глобале. Т.е. в функциях придется делать так (именно в этом порядке):

```
function a() {
  new MyClass('lol');
  global $lol;
  var_dump($lol);
  }
```

Comment: Да неплохо, спасибо, не совсем то, что я хотел но по-моему мне пойдет.

Comment: А можно внутри конструктора определить с помощью магических констант, кем вызван конструктор и заставить в любом случае создавать глобальную переменную?

Comment: Она и так в любом случае создается глобально =) Ну и кстати никто же не запрещает написать в локале 

    $lol = new MyClass('lol');

В этом случае просто в глобале будет создана ссылка `$GLOBALS['lol']`, причем и локальное $lol, и глобальное $lol, и $GLOBALS['lol'] будут ссылаться на один объект.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Соотвественно в деструкторе надо указывать 
<pre>unset($GLOBALS['lol'])</pre>

Comment: Про деструктор не подумал. Тогда логично еще `$objectName` запилить в объект как *private*, а в деструторе

    unset($GLOBALS[$this->objectName]);